# Does the smp tag need a rename?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

What do you think of the [smp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smp) tag? Does it need to be renamed to something more easily understandable, or can it stand on its own? Does it even need to be its own tag?

> It's apparently for questions about Minecraft's **S**urvival **M**ulti**p**layer mode. If you had to read this to understand what the tag is about, you'll probably agree it needs a synonym.

Comment: For some reason, even though I kept on seeing this tag around, I thought it had something to do with servers so I let it stick around. Whoops.

Comment: @mana that's the problem

Answer (score 18):

I think it should be renamed to [minecraft-smp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-smp). It isn't obvious to anyone who isn't a Minecraft player what that is, and it's not a game acronym.

Comment: I second this, it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Yeah, either this or [minecraft-survival] or... something :) That's why I'm asking.

Comment: smp *still* doesn't make sense to me. (I suppose that's because my brain tries to turn the acronym into (**S**ingle **P**layer **M**ode)

Comment: Why not [minecraft-multiplayer]? That way there's no confusion for people who don't actually know what SMP stands for (or people like @Raven who easily forget :)

Answer (score -4):

I think that [smp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/smp) is fine as it is.  The tag isn't obvious to anyone who isn't a Minecraft player, but it will only ever be used in conjunction with the [minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft) tag anyway.